# serving pytorch model using flask

Tags: python, multithreading, flask, machine-learning, pytorch

If multiple clients make a request to one server(pytorch model), how does the problem arise in the multithread of the flask or elsewhere?

As far as I know, if running the pytorch model with multithreading using flask, the data will get tangled. If I’m wrong, please correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a multithreaded approach for `Flask` as well, the request will get throttled if you just initiate a single threaded usual `Flask` server.

Use `Gunicorn`: https://gunicorn.org/ to start your Flask server, with a good number of threads, passed as a parameter value to `Gunicorn`.